# Trying to get value from json object

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON: Full json coming from [here](https://api.import.io/store/connector/6cc86d93-9a64-4068-b9e2-8dc6c3239bfe/_query?input=webpage/url:http%3A%2F%2Fcoinmarketcap.com%2F&&_apikey=1ecdbfaa5b6a4e99b4ac28e155faad363521bf2ee092218e5230734bd9af72c0a58ff2dcaeeefaf76b86d608e507439d2c4a387961de01947a6c9592f4d19bb23b47c25d666d1541bd6e7f892d7ac2c1). I tried to follow [this](http://api.docs.import.io/) but I am having a hard time doing so

```
results: [
    {
        marketcap_price/_currency: "USD",
        available_link_numbers/_source: "15,045,750",
        marketcap_price/_source: "$ 6,509,092,365",
        number: 1,
        name_link/_text: "Bitcoin",
        name_link/_source: "/currencies/bitcoin/",
        number/_source: "1",
        price_link/_source: "/currencies/bitcoin/#markets",
        available_link: "http://blockchain.info",
        name_image/_source: "/static/img/coins/16x16/bitcoin.png",
        price_link/_text: "$ 432.62",
        pricegraph7d_link/_source: "/currencies/bitcoin/#charts",
        price_link: "http://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/#markets",
        pricegraph7d_image: "https://files.coinmarketcap.com/generated/sparklines/1.png",
        volume24h_link/_source: "/currencies/bitcoin/#markets",
        change24h_value: "0.39 %"
    }
]
```

When I do

```
echo $obj->results[0]->number;
```

it outputs the value

```
 1
```

BUT when I try to do

```
echo $obj->results[0]->price_link/_text;
```

It gives me nothing. I am using PHP for this. It should output

```
$432.62
```

Any way for me to get that price value? What am I doing wrong? Also, is it possible to get the value with just the numbers and no '$' symbol?

Comment: please update your question with your exact json string, what you have now is invalid json, you can verify it at jsonlint.com

Comment: Could you please try doing the following: `$obj = json_decode($variable, true);` and then trying to echo `$obj['results']['price_link/_text'];`

Comment: Is the usage of `/` in the properties name is something you can change? I'm not sure if PHP supports the usage of that character in properties names.

Comment: I have updated with the location from where the json is coming from

Comment: I am not able to change the /. It comes from www.import.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`price_link/_text` is not valid PHP variable name. You have to use one of following approach:

Use `{}` for custom name: `$obj->results[0]->{'price_link/_text'}`

Access data as array: `$obj['results'][0]['price_link/_text']` (use `json_decode($json, true)` to get information as array).

Comment: `$obj->results[0]->{'price_link/_text'}` worked